# Adding a new Column to existing SAS dataset

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset that I have created by reading in a .txt file. It has about 20-25 rows and I'd like to add a new column that assigns an alphabet in serial order to each row.

Row 1 A

Row 2 B

Row 3 C
.......

It sounds like a really basic question and one that should have an easy solution, but unfortunately, I'm unable to find this anywhere. I get solutions for adding new calculated columns and so on, but in my case, I just want to add a new column to my existing  datatable - there is no other relation between the variables.

Comment: I was thinking on option would be just creating a new table, say new_table which has the same number of rows and only a single column containing my data. After this, use a full outer join (or something along those lines) to just combine the two horizontally. I'm not certain this would work, and even then, I'd appreciate a more elegant method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of ugly and if you have more than 26 rows it will start to use random ascii characters.  But it does solve the problem as defined by the question.

**Test data:**

```
data have;
  do row = 1 to 26;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

**Explanation:**

On my computer, the letter 'A' is at position 65 in the ASCII table (YMMV).  We can determine this by using this code:

```
data _null_;
  pos = rank('A');
  put pos=;
run;
```

The ASCII table will position the alphabet sequentially, so that `B` will be at position `66` (if `A` is at `65` and so on).

The `byte()` function returns a character from the ASCII table at a certain position.  We can take advantage of this by using the position of ASCII character `A` as an offset, subtracting 1, then adding the row number (`_n_`) to it.

**Final Solution:**

```
data want;
  set have;      
  alphabet = byte(rank('A')-1 + _n_);
run;
```

Comment: This looks promising! Yes, I only have about 20 rows, so it shouldn't be a problem. Looking into this right away. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not better than Tom's but a brute force alternative essentially. Create the string of Alpha and then use CHAR() to identify character of interest.

```
data want;
  set sashelp.class;
  retain string 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  letter = char(string, _n_);
run;
```