# SAS: Insert multiple columns or rows in a specific position of an existing dataset

Tags: sas

Goal: Add one or more empty rows after a specific position in the dataset

Here's the work I've done so far:

```
data test_data;
    set sashelp.class;
    output;

    /* Add a blank line after row 5*/
    if _n_ = 5 then do;
        call missing(of _all_);
        output;
    end;

    /* Add 4 blank rows after row 7*/

    if _n_ = 7 then do;
        /* inserts a blank row after row 8 (7 original rows + 1 blank row) */
        call missing(of _all_);

        /*repeats the newly created blank row: inserts 3 blank rows*/
        do i = 1 to 3;
            output;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

I'm still learning how to use SAS, but I "feel" like there's a better way to get to the same result, chiefly not having to use a for loop to insert multiple empty rows. Doing this several times, I lose track of which values *n* should be as well. I was wondering:

1. Is there a better way to do this for rows?
2. Is there an equivalent for columns? ([A similar question probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884975/adding-a-new-column-to-existing-sas-dataset))
3. These rows/columns are being added more to fit a report format. The dataset doesn't need these blank rows/columns for its own sake. Is some PROC or REPORT function that achieves the same thing?

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? Just adding empty observations into a dataset does not make any sense.  Are you making a presentation? Are you trying to create a data file that some other application is going to read?  Do you have specifications that you are trying to meet?  Is your source dataset missing some values? Do you have a data source for the full set of values you want to merge with?

Comment: That is correct: These blanks are added more for a report/presentation than for the data itself. At the moment, the resulting dataset gets exported to an Excel sheet that requires these blank rows/columns. I can't change the Excel sheet. I agree that adding blank rows/sheet to the dataset itself doesn't make any sense for its own sake. Source dataset is not missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to add blanks to your report after each group of observations?
For example lets make a dummy dataset with a group variable.

```
data test_data ;
  set sashelp.class ;
  if _n_ <= 5 then group=1;
  else if _n_ <=7 then group=2 ;
  else group=3 ;
run;
```

Now we can make a report that adds two blank lines after each group.

```
proc report data=test_data ;
  column group name age ;
  define group / group noprint ;
  define name / display ;
  define age / display;
  compute after group ;
     line @1 ' ';
     line @1 ' ';
  endcomp;
run;
```

Or is it the case that your report data does not have all possible values and you want your output to have all possible values?

So we wanted a report that counts how many kids in our class by age and we need to report for ages 10 to 18.  But there are no 10 year olds in our class.  Make a dummy table and merge with that.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.class ;
  tables age / noprint out=counts;
run;

proc print data=counts;
run;

data shell;
  do age=10 to 18;
    retain count 0 percent 0;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want ;
  merge shell counts  ;
  by age;
run;

proc print data=want ;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, that would achieve some of the goal. if I wanted the number of blank lines to be dependent on the group number, is there just a small modification to the "Compute after group"? For example, only one blank line after the first group, 3 blanks lines after the second group, and none in the third group?

Comment: That is harder in PROC REPORT as I don't think LINE statements are conditional.  You can try using $VARYING. format with length of 0 to suppress a line.  But if the max for any group is three lines then you need three LINE statements. It does not help to put the LINE statement in a DO loop.

Comment: @instantwipe2000 It sounds like you need a fixed number of records per some sort of group. If this is the case, create a shell table with the key number of records and merge your data with it to obtain the desired results.